# Как разделить вывод из компонента Битрикс по свойству инфоблока

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть инфоблок  с товарами , у товара есть свойства

> Новинка, Акция , Хит продаж

. В настройках компонента настроен фильтр по этим свойствам. Вот так

> `ИЛИ Акция ИЛИ Новинка ИЛИ Хит продаж`

На страницу выводятся все товары со свойством Акция, Новинка, Хит продаж в разнобой.

Как разделить этот вывод ? по какому ключу массива? Ну например чтобы в одном `div` разместить только Акции, в другом только Новинки и.т.д

Comment: Вывести массив этих элементов и разобраться что в них где.

Answer (score 0):

В шаблоне компонента в файле result_modifier.php можно произвести дополнительную обработку массива $arResult, что бы на основе параметров компонента или данных из запроса (или ещё чего нибудь) подготовить новый массив данных и вывести его, как надо в шаблоне компонента.

Comment: Задан конкретный вопрос: как раскидать результаты по трём разным дивам. Ну, подготовили Вы в result_modifier.php новый массив - дальше что? Как Вы в одном цикле раскидаете по трём дивам результаты? Хотелось бы пример кода увидеть. Пока это не является ответом на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

для каждого дива вызвать компонент с нужным фильтром, и настроить кеширование

Comment: пробывал, да вполне работает. Спасибо.  Но громоздко, не нравится.